# Update en SQL con order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito actualizar una tabla por bloques de 100. Es decir actualizar primero 100, pasados dos días otros 100 y así hasta completar el total de registros de la tabla.

El problema es que necesito actualizar los registro por fecha de manera descendente. He intentado hacerlo con las siguientes consultas:

```
Update top (100) DUMMYTABLE
set ESTADO = 3 
where ESTADO = 5 order by FECHACREACION desc
```

Lo que da sintaxis incorrecta.

También he intentado:

```
Update top (100) DUMMYTABLE 
set ESTADO = 3
where ESTADO = 5 and id in (select top(100) * from DUMMYTABLE where ESTADO = 5 order by FECHACREACION desc)
```

Pero me da el siguiente mensaje de error: Sólo se puede especificar una expresión en la lista de selección cuando la subconsulta no se especifica con EXISTS.

He encontrado esta [respuesta aceptada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655010/how-to-update-and-order-by-using-ms-sql) en so en inglés, pero a mi me da el mismo error que al lanzar la segunda consulta.

Gracias por adelantado!

Comment: Tu segunda consulta necesita cambiar el asterisco por `id`. De cualquier forma, te recomiendo que mejor uses la solución de Mikel Ferreiro,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías probar a usar las [Common Table Expresions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/warnov/2010/12/12/cte-common-table-expressions-sql-server-2008/) de sql-server de la siguiente forma:

```
 with cte as (
   select top (100)
       ESTADO
   from DUMMYTABLE 
   where ESTADO = 5 order by FECHACREACION desc
)
update cte set
    ESTADO = 'P'
```

Comment: Perfect! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Crea un campo de fecha_actualización inicializado en NULL en la tabla DUMMYTABLE, cada vez que actualices un registro que actualice con la fecha actual GETDATE(). Luego crea una tabla temporal en donde estén los 100 registros que quieras actualizar y filtras los que tengan el campo fecha_actualización en NULL.

```
SELECT TOP 100 * INTO #tablaTemporal from DUMMYTABLE WHERE ESTADO = 5 AND fecha_actualización IS NULL order by FECHACREACION desc
```

Luego actualizas el campo uniendo la tabla temporal con la tabla DUMMYTABLE por su clave.

```
UPDATE C SET C.Estado=3, C.fecha_actualización = GETDATE() FROM DUMMYTABLE C INNER JOIN #tablaTemporal T ON T.ID=C.ID
```